# Is there a way to replace from original string to translated string in .po file

Tags: translation, gettext, po

I want to switch the string from translated string in .po file to original string in source file.

i.e:

in **en.po**

```
#: hello.py:100
msgid "안녕"
msgstr "hello"
```

in **hello.py**

```
...
print(_(u'안녕'))
....
```

> something --pofile en.po --source [directory in hello.py] --destination [directory for hello_replaced.py]

it will be :

in **hello_replaced.py**

```
...
print(_(u'hello'))
...
```

Is there any useful tool?

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Please show us what you've attempted.

Comment: post you code , thanks

Comment: ^^ posted code. thanks